# How to rotate Oculus left in UnrealEngine separately

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculus, blueprint

I need to rotate Oculus CV1 left and right eyes images on gamepad Thumbstick separately (left independently on right one) by useing BluePrints. ChatGPT says StereoLayer has left and right eyes option in Details but I can't find it in three versions of UnrealEngine I have: 4.8, 4.24, 4.27.

I tried to make one camera and cine camera and two StereoLaers in BluePrint but can't handle how to watch images from each cam by each eye.